# How to see the temperatures of the parts of my MacBook on Monterey?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey, temperature

How can I see the temperatures recorded by every sensor inside of my MacBook 2015?

Back in 2017 it apparently wasn't possible without external apps (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/291511/150109), of which I found these three: [How can I find out the temperature of my Macbook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/168867/150109)

What's the most lightweight way to read the temperatures now on Monterey in 2022?

How can I do it using only built-in tools, or which app that can do so takes the least storage?